# Where is my .rpi-sdimg (Yocto Project - Toaster)?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, meta-raspberrypi

I am currently trying to build a simple image for my raspberry pi 2 using toaster, the web gui of yocto project.

Everything works fine and the build succeds.

Every tutorial I've found is telling me to use dd on the file "core-image-weston-raspberrypi2.rpi-sdimg".

Sadly there is no such file on my pc.

Did someone had the same problem and managed to fix it?

Please find attached the Configuration and BitBake Variables:

[image: Configuration]

[image: BitBakeVariables]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check what's the value of the IMAGE_FSTYPES variable in your build? Click the image recipe name in one of your finished builds, then the "configuration" link on the left hand side, and select the "BitBake variables" tab. Once there, search for IMAGE_FSTYPES.

If the value of IMAGE_FSTYPES does not include "rpi-sdimg", you will need to add it. If you are using Toaster from the Yocto Project master branch (it looks like you are from your screenshots), you can do that from Toaster. Go to the "BitBake variables" page in the project configuration, click the "change" icon next to the value of IMAGE_FSTYPES, then type "rpi-sdimg" at the end of the variable value. After that you will need to rebuild the core-image-weston-raspberrypi2 image.

In theory, this should generate the core-image-weston-raspberrypi2.rpi-sdimg file you need (unless something in the meta-raspberrypi layer is dictating otherwise).

If you are not using the master branch, Toaster will have a bug that prevents you from adding custom values to IMAGE_FSTYPES, but you can still do so by editing the configuration files.